# Rectangle not repeating on multiple pages with table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a rectangle which contains a Table (i.e. Tablix1) and a rectangle (i.e. Rectangle1) in it side by side like this.

[image]

Now my table data is spanning to multiple pages in PDF and I want the contents in my rectangle to repeat on every page of PDF as it is.

I have tried setting Tablix1 in **RepeatWith** property of the Rectangle1 but it is not giving my the desired result. Rectangle1 is only showing on the first page.

Can any one guide if I am missing something here or is there any other approach to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure rectangle 1 is actually inside the main rectangle and doesn't just look that way? On occasion it will look to be inside but in reality its separate.  An easy check would be to drag main rectangle and see if rectangle 1 moves with it.  If it does then I don't know the answer off the top of my head, if it doesn't then select rectangle 1, ctrl-x to cut, manually select main rectangle, ctrl-v paste, this will make sure they are "linked". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ralph for pointing this out. But I have already checked it multiple times..
Rectanlge1 is part of main rectangle.. and moves with it.

Comment: I have checked. It is only causing an issue when rendering to PDF. If I see the report  in report viewer with multiple pages, the rectangle repeats just fine.